# Extract information from text file using PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table, text-files, fopen

**Problem:**

Extracting information from text file using PHP based on a structure that is as following:

- Date (in the format YYYY-MM-DD)
- Title
- Text: value
- Text: value
- Text: value

**Input:**

```
2015-03-18
 Store A
Text 1: 5,00 USD
Text 2: 2015-03-18
Text 3: 2015-03-12
 Store B
Text 1: 10,00 USD
Text 2: 2015-03-18
Text 3: 2015-03-12
 Store C
Text 1: 15,00 USD
Text 2: 2015-03-18
Text 3: 2015-03-12
2015-03-19
 Store D
Text 1: 20,00 USD
Text 2: 2015-03-18
Text 3: 2015-03-12
```

**PHP Code (so far):**

```
<?php
    // Creates array to store data from textfile
    $data       = array();

    // Opens text file
    $text_file  = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

    // Loops through each line
    while ($line = fgets($text_file))
    {
        // Checks whether line is a date
        if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/", trim($line)))
        {
            $data[$line] = array();
        }
        else
        {
            $data[] = trim($line);
        }
    }

    // Removes first array key
    $data = array_slice($data, 1);

    // Prints out full array
    echo "<xmp>" . print_r($data, true) . "</xmp>";
 ?>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Store</th>
    <th>Text 1</th>
    <th>Text 2</th>
    <th>Text 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015-03-18</td>
    <td>Store A</td>
    <td>5,00 USD</td>
    <td>2015-03-18</td>
    <td>2015-03-12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Store B</td>
    <td>10,00 USD</td>
    <td>2015-03-18</td>
    <td>2015-03-12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Store C</td>
    <td>15,00 USD</td>
    <td>2015-03-18</td>
    <td>2015-03-12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015-03-19</td>
    <td>Store D</td>
    <td>20,00 USD</td>
    <td>2015-03-18</td>
    <td>2015-03-12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Desired output:**

[image]

**Questions:**

1. What is the appropriate way to extract and store the different
   values?
2. What is the appropriate way to print out the information
   as the output example?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @kexxcream are you able to match the dates OK? If so, the output is not that hard. Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: @JayBlanchard The dates work fine. I have been able to add it to the array. What I am stuck with is how to detect what kind of information is in the different rows. I have updated the code.

Comment: From what I can see @kexxcream you don't need to detect what kind of data is in each line save for the date. If the date exists it goes in the first cell of that line, if it doesn't the first cell is empty.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I understand, how would I proceed to include the store information + the different values under respective date?

Comment: You're outputting table rows, so if there is no date you would include a blank table cell. Give me a few minutes and I'll write an example.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Got it, but I'm right now at trying to put the different values in an array which I want to use later to print everything out. I managed now to sort the stores under each date. But how would I go about to sort the different values for each store?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - sort *which* values?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Assigning each store an array and adding Text 1, Text 2, Text 3 to it. That way Text 1, 2 and 3 gets sorted for each store. Sorry for not being clear from the beginning.

Comment: If each row has 5 columns you don't have to test to see where the date is, just store each item until you get to 5. It becomes a lot more complicated if you don't know how many columns there will be.

Comment: *Curious:* Why not use a database for this? It would be so much simpler. Is there a specific reason why you're not using a database?

Comment: @Fred-ii- The information is only provided in text format.

Comment: If you assign each store an array then you can use array sorting methods on the data. I fear that you haven't given us a complete picture. Is it possible that the data in the file will not be sorted? You could take the text provided and put it into a database yourself.

Comment: Your welcome :) - Any queries then feel free to post comments. I will answer them.

Comment: @RyanVincent How would I go about to only print out only store groups that is current date and forward? In this case, 18/3 store group would not be printed out since it's 19/3 today.

Comment: drat - there is a failure if the last group in the file is the one skipped. No more edits to this answer. New, complete code can be found here: [Pastebin - questions 29121286](http://pastebin.com/6qSk4n54).

Comment: @RyanVincent It looks great, I highly appreciate your time for this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interested in the 'groups' of records in the source file.

Date group - indicated by the a line with just a date on it

- Store Group - consists of..
- store name
- price
- a group of dates

**Added Requirement**: print out only store groups that is current date and forward? I will call this the 'cutoff_date' in the code.

I use a 'read-ahead' technique so there is always a record to process

I supply functions to help 'identify things'. They are used so it is easier to see the controlling' logic.

The code:

```
<?php // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121286/extract-information-from-text-file-using-php

/**
 * We need to only show store entries on or after a certain date
 * i call this the 'cutoff_date'.
 *
 * It will default to todays date
 */
$now = new DateTime();
$CUTOFF_DATE = $now->format('Y-m-d');

// output stored in here
$outHtml = '<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Store</th>
    <th>Text 1</th>
    <th>Text 2</th>
    <th>Text 3</th>
  </tr>';


// source - we use 'read-ahead' as it makes life easier
$sourceFile = fopen(__DIR__ . '/Q29121286.txt', 'rb');

$currentLine = readNextLine($sourceFile); // read-ahead

while (!empty($currentLine)) { // process until eof...

    // start of a date group...
    $currentGroupDate = $currentLine; // ignore this group if less than CUTOFF_DATE
    $currentLine = readNextLine($sourceFile); // read ahead

    while (!empty($currentGroupDate) && $currentGroupDate < $CUTOFF_DATE) { // find next date_group record
        while (!empty($currentLine) && datePosition($currentLine) !== 0) { // read to end of current group
            $currentLine = readNextLine($sourceFile);
        }
        $currentGroupDate = $currentLine;
        $currentLine = readNextLine($sourceFile); // read ahead
   }

    $htmlCurrentDate = $currentGroupDate; // only print the date once

    $html = '';
    // display all the rows for this 'date group' -- look for next 'date'
    while (!empty($currentLine) && datePosition($currentLine) !== 0) {

        $html = '<tr>';

        $html .= '<td>'. $htmlCurrentDate .'</td>';
        $htmlCurrentDate = ''; // only display the date once

        $html .= '<td>'. $currentLine .'</td>'; // store
        $currentLine = readNextLine($sourceFile);

        // process the price
         $lineParts = explode(':', $currentLine); // need the price...
         $html .= '<td>'. $lineParts[1] .'</td>';
         $currentLine = readNextLine($sourceFile);

        // now process the group of dates - look for a line
        // that starts with 'text' and must contain a date
        while (   !empty($currentLine)
                && isTextLine($currentLine)
                && datePosition($currentLine) >= 1) {

            $lineParts = explode(':', $currentLine); // need the date...
            $html .= '<td>'. $lineParts[1] .'</td>';
            $currentLine = readNextLine($sourceFile); // read next
        }

        // end of this group...
        $html .= '</tr>';

        $outHtml .= $html;

    } // end of 'dateGroup'
} // end of data file...

$outHtml .= '</table>';
fclose($sourceFile);


// display output
echo $outHtml;
exit;

/**
 * These routines hide the low-level processing;
 */

/**
 * Return position of date string - will be -1 if not found
 * @param type $line
 * @return integer
 */
function datePosition($line)
{
    $result = preg_match("/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/", $line, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $pos = -1;
    if (!empty($matches)) {
        $match = current($matches);
        $pos = $match[1];
    }
    return $pos;
}

/**
 * return whether line is a text line
 *
 * @param type $text
 * @return type
 */
function isTextLine($text)
{
    return strpos(strtolower($text), 'text') === 0;
}

/**
 * return trimmed string or an empty string at eof
 * Added 'fudge' to not read passed the eof - ;-/
 * @param type $handle
 * @return string
 */
function readNextLine($handle)
{
    static $isEOF = false;

    if ($isEOF) {
        return '';
    }

    $line = fgets($handle);
    if ($line !== false) {
        $line = trim($line);
    }
    else {
        $isEOF = true;
        $line = '';
    }
    return $line;
}
```

Original output from the supplied file:

```
| Date       | Store   | Text 1    | Text 2     | Text 3     |
|------------|---------|-----------|------------|------------|
| 2015-03-18 | Store A | 5,00 USD  | 2015-03-18 | 2015-03-12 |
|            | Store B | 10,00 USD | 2015-03-18 | 2015-03-12 |
|            | Store C | 15,00 USD | 2015-03-18 | 2015-03-12 |
| 2015-03-19 | Store D | 20,00 USD | 2015-03-18 | 2015-03-12 |
```

Comment: You nailed it, and saved the day. Thanks a lot! Now it's time for me to go through the code extensively and learn what you have done.